# Authoring plugins jQuery documentation

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm toying around a bit with authoring plugins so I turned to the jQuery documentation where it was talking about not cluttering the $.fn object and how no single plugin should ever claim more than on $.fn namespace...

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { 
      // THIS 
   },
    show : function( ) {
      // IS
    },
    hide : function( ) { 
      // GOOD
    },
    update : function( content ) { 
      // !!! 
    }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
  return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );

// calls the init method
$('div').tooltip(); 

// calls the init method
$('div').tooltip({
  foo : 'bar'
});
```

I understood everything up until the:

```
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
```

part.

I changed that bit to simply:

```
$.fn.tooltip = function(method)
{
    if(myFunc[method])
    {
        return myFunc[method].apply();
    }
}
```

and it works just fine... Can someone please explain to me exactly what's going on there and why mine seemed to work just fine?

EDIT: By the way, I know I didn't continue the if/else structure entirely, that's because I'm purely focused on the line I mentioned and not the remaining part of the if structure.

Comment: Your way assumes none of your "methods" require additional parameters. If they need additional parameters, you would need to add them. YOu could have even simplified it further to `return myFunc[method]()`

Comment: Can you elaborate anymore? perhaps given an example of how I'd add additional parameters?

Really I'm just trying to understand what's going on with the jQuery's documentation example.

Comment: For example, if your plugin had a "jump" method, you would want to give it a "height" parameter. `$(el).myPlugin("jump","3ft")`. If you remove all that extra stuff from the original code, you wouldn't be able to pass on the `"3ft"` part to the method.

Comment: Ah, it just clicked, thanks man! If you construct an answer to this topic I'll go ahead and check it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of doing it works fine, however, it won't allow you to pass any parameters on to your methods.

For example, If your plugin had an `option` method that allowed you to change the tooltip text option, you would call it like this:

```
$(element).tooltip("option","text","foobar!!");
```

If you remove all that other code and use your way of doing it, the `option` method wouldn't receive the `"text"` or `"foobar!!!"` parameters.